# Is there a way to programmatically find the current used GPU (C, C++)?

Tags: c++, c, gpu, cpu

In the case of CPUs, the (linux specific) sys calls `getcpu()` or `sched_getcpu()` can be used inside a program to obtain the ID of the core executing them. For example, in the case of a 4 processors system, the logical index returned by the mentionned calls makes it possible to deduce which one of the 4 CPUs is being used (let's say every CPU contains 10 cores, therefore if `sched_getcpu()` returns 20, that means the CPU #2 is being used since the core number 20 is in the 3rd CPU).

How can I achieve a similar thing in the case of GPUs? Is there a way to find which one is being used in real time from inside an application?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Most applications don't utilize the GPU, since you need to explicitly acquire GPU resources.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info, although some of the answers on that question are very dated and I'm sure the tools have changed

Comment: @WillOw None of the answers in the link you mentionned provide an answer on how to **programmatically** get the **current used** GPU. Note that I also explicitly wrote "**inside a program**", "**from inside an application**" and "**C/C++**".

Comment: @ReyReddington there is no current used GPU unless you explicitly requested GPU usage, so you need to show/explain how you did that

Comment: If the system has OpenGL, you can get GPU info from OpenGL context, specifically `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER`. For this Linux desktop I get 'NVIDIA Corporation' and 'GeForce GT 720/PCIe/SSE2`. To do this without opening a GL window see the source for glxinfo.c for your platform. If OpenGL hardware drivers aren't installed you'll get "Microsoft" or "Mesa" or similar for vendor. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_information_queries

Comment: This is not a C++ question as it is not part of the language. This is more an OS like question on how a specific OS provides that information to an application.

Comment: `linux specific` I beleive this is still not specific enough. I will guess that nvidia driver has completely different interface than noveau or radeon. There is no general answer - there may be a way to get gpu usage _for your specific system configuration for your specific graphic card_ (there may be not, as the driver might not support it, or there _may be no gpu at all_), and then you have to build "up" - handle each possible configuration and combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has no concept of a GPU. You got a great comment pointing you to the right direction of getting some GPU info using OpenGL, I'm sure there are other cross platform libraries as well.

Take a look at the source code of [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) which is a command-line system info tool which, among other things, gets your GPU(s). It uses a bunch of different methods to get the GPU on the current system, some of which may help point you to the right direction. For example, for linux systems it gets the gpu info using `lspci -mm`:

```
echo $(lspci -mm | awk -F '\"|\" \"|\\(' \
'/"Display|"3D|"VGA/ {
a[$0] = $1 " " $3 " " ($(NF-1) ~ /^$|^Device [[:xdigit:]]+$/ ? $4 : $(NF-1))
}
END { for (i in a) {
if (!seen[a[i]]++) {
sub("^[^ ]+ ", "", a[i]);
print a[i]
}
}}')
```

which returns `NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]` for my system. But this is not cross platform. If you wanted to do it yourself you would thus have to either:

- implement a way for every system your application will run on
- lose cross-platform ability

Or simply use OpenGL as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the API you are using to access the GPU. Under vulkan, the capability to query the available devices is provided in the API itself. e.g.

```cpp
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices    //< use to iterate over devices 
vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties //< use to determine make/model
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures   //< use to determine the capabilities
```

Under OpenGL, this is a little harder, because the API doesn't really provide a nice robust way of iterating over connected GPU's *(this is very much left to the underlying OS)*. Aside from calling `glGetString` with GL_VENDOR, and/or GL_RENDERER, *after* the context has been created, that's about all you have got.

With graphics API's in general, you will typically choose the device to use up front, and then forget about it. *(i.e. you know which GPU is in use, because it's the one you requested)*

So for example, on windows you'd use the WIn32 API call `EnumDisplayDevices` to iterate over a bunch of `DISPLAY_DEVICE` structures, which give you a breakdown of the GPU devices. If you then want to query the device capabilities, you'd need to initialise an OpenGL context (with the correct device), and make multiple calls to glGetIntegerv to query the actual capabilities.

Sadly, on linux this is a little trickier. Iterating the display devices is pretty much going to depend on the underlying API you are using to initialise the GPU *(e.g. GLX, SDL, Qt, etc)*.

So for example, in SDL you would iterate over the available devices using `SDL_GetRenderDriverInfo`, before passing your preferred device index  to `SDL_CreateRenderer` at app startup.